# Apache Beam TextIO.read().from() does not interpret escaped special character in filepattern

Tags: apache-beam

#### Environment

- Java SDK 2.33.0

#### Setup

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/beam
$ echo "test" >> "/tmp/beam/test*.txt"
```

#### Test pipeline

```java
public class PipelineTest {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    Pipeline p = TestPipeline.create().enableAbandonedNodeEnforcement(false);

    String filename = "/tmp/beam/test\\*.txt";

    PCollection<String> input = p.apply(TextIO.read().from(filename));
    PAssert.that(input).containsInAnyOrder("test");

    p.run();
  }
}
```

This test fails with below messages.

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 10.66 s <<< FAILURE! - in PipelineTest
[ERROR] test  Time elapsed: 10.645 s  <<< ERROR!
org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No files matched spec: /tmp/beam/test\*.txt
        at PipelineTest.test(PipelineTest.java:28)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No files matched spec: /tmp/beam/test\*.txt
```

How can I read files that contain asterisks or other special characters?

Answer (score 0):

For now you'll simply have to rename such files. I've filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-13231

Comment: Thanks for the response and for creating the issue.
The same problem may occur with other glob patterns such as `?`, `[..]`

Comment: Good point, commented on the JIRA about this.